# Blob in query with joins to create a view

Tags: sql, oracle

I am struggling with a blob-type-column to join it to a view with multiple joins in it.
The blob-type is the **MAINAPL.GRAPHICS.GRAF** and highlighted below in my query.
I get following Error from my Oracle Database:

ORA-00932 and it leads to exactly that column.

Is there a possibility to join the blob-type anyways? I need it as a normal column in this complex view.

*My main query is this:*

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW SECAPL.VIEW_DATAFEED2 AS
SELECT
MIN(CASE WHEN MAINAPL.ARTCOPY.SPRID = 'EN' AND MAINAPL.ARTCOPY.ARTCOPYNUM = 1 THEN MAINAPL.ARTCOPY.ART-COPY-1 ELSE NULL END ) COPY1-EN, 
MAX(CASE WHEN MAINAPL.CONT.TONGID = 'EN' AND MAINAPL.CLASS1.CLASSTFRLE1 = '1' THEN MAINAPL.CONT.COPY-ONLY END) AS TYPE-EN,
MAINAPL.ARTICLEGRAPHICS.GRAPHID,
**MAINAPL.GRAPHICS.GRAF**,
MAINAPL.GRAPHICS.GRAFFORMAT
FROM
MAINAPL.ARTICLE
LEFT JOIN MAINAPL.ARTCOPY ON MAINAPL.ARTICLE.ARTID = MAINAPL.ARTCOPY.ARTID
INNER JOIN MAINAPL.ARTICLEGRAPHICS ON MAINAPL.ARTICLE.ARTID = MAINAPL.ARTICLEGRAPHICS.ARTID
INNER JOIN MAINAPL.GRAPHICS ON MAINAPL.GRAPHICS.GRAPHICSID = MAINAPL.ARTICLEGRAPHICS.GRAPHICSID

GROUP BY MAINAPL.ARTICLE.ARTID,
MAINAPL.ARTICLEGRAPHICS.GRAPHID,
**MAINAPL.GRAPHICS.GRAF**,
MAINAPL.GRAPHICS.GRAFFORMAT
```

Comment: Unreadable wall of code - please give a [MCVE] and strip out all the columns and extra joins that are not part of this problem and just leave a small piece of example code that illustrates the issue. Then give the (again, minimal) DDL statements for the tables in your minimal example. Please don't make us read through 500 line queries to pick out the 3 relevant lines!

Comment: Done. Thank you for your advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are trying to group by the blob column. You can work around that easily. Use two selects. The first select is basically what you have but without the blob (and possibly without other columns that can be fetched later). You still get the graphid. The second outer select joins the inner select with the mainapl.grapics table on graphid and returns everything including the blob. Hope that made sense?

EDIT:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW SECAPL.VIEW_DATAFEED2 AS
  select sub.copy1-en, sub.type-en, sub.graphicsid,
     graph.graf, graph.grafformat
  from (SELECT
          MIN(CASE WHEN MAINAPL.ARTCOPY.SPRID = 'EN' AND MAINAPL.ARTCOPY.ARTCOPYNUM = 1 THEN MAINAPL.ARTCOPY.ART-COPY-1 ELSE NULL END ) COPY1-EN, 
          MAX(CASE WHEN MAINAPL.CONT.TONGID = 'EN' AND MAINAPL.CLASS1.CLASSTFRLE1 = '1' THEN MAINAPL.CONT.COPY-ONLY END) AS TYPE-EN,
          MAINAPL.ARTICLEGRAPHICS.GRAPHICSID
        FROM MAINAPL.ARTICLE
        LEFT JOIN MAINAPL.ARTCOPY ON MAINAPL.ARTICLE.ARTID = MAINAPL.ARTCOPY.ARTID
        INNER JOIN MAINAPL.ARTICLEGRAPHICS ON MAINAPL.ARTICLE.ARTID = MAINAPL.ARTICLEGRAPHICS.ARTID
        INNER JOIN MAINAPL.GRAPHICS ON MAINAPL.GRAPHICS.GRAPHICSID = MAINAPL.ARTICLEGRAPHICS.GRAPHICSID
        GROUP BY MAINAPL.ARTICLEGRAPHICS.GRAPHICSID
        ) sub
  join MAINAPL.GRAPHICS ON MAINAPL.GRAPHICS.GRAPHICSID = sub.GRAPHICSID
```

This may not work, but should illustrate the point. I rewrote the inner SQL a bit as you seemed to group by too much, I'm not sure if that was good or bad. I also corrected a possible mistake with the graphicsid column name.

Anyway, the point should be clear - find the records you need with an inner SQL that includes the id you need in order to fetch the blob in the outer SQL.

Comment: I am sorry, I do not understand. Could you please make an example?

Comment: I added an example, better now?

Comment: I see... logically, a nested one. Thank you! That works!